# html select tag change from checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

how can i do when some option is checked in checkbox, that label showing in select tag?
[image]

Checkbox input

```
<input
type="checkbox"
class="toggle-product pull-right" @if(!isset($restrictedProductIds[$p->id])) checked
@endif
data-url="{{route('image.settings.product.toggle',[$account,$album,$image,$p])}}">
```

Select tag

```
                    <select name="default_id" id="default_id" class="form-control">
                    <option value="{{$image->default_product_id}}" selected>{{$image->default_product_id}}</option>
                    @foreach($validProducts as $product)
                        @if(!isset($restrictedProductIds[$product->id]))
                        <option value="{{$product->id}}">
                            {{$product->getTranslatedName()}}
                        </option>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </select>
```

class .toggle-product

```js
            $(".toggle-product").on('click', function () {
                var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
                var $status = $(this).parents(".list-group-item");
                $status.addClass('list-group-item-warning');
                $.post($(this).data('url'), {
                    'enabled': checked ? 1 : 0,
                    '_token': "{{csrf_token()}}"
                }, function (response) {
                    $status.removeClass('list-group-item-warning');
                    //location.reload();
                }.bind(this))
            });
```

Comment: on means on change of select options those related options in checkbox will be checked right ?

Comment: what is the connection between option and respective checkbox?

Comment: @rahul_m Yes, i want select option show from checked checkbox on real time, without refresh.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar MySQL, but i want this all on real time, if user checkMug un realtime he can select show Mug without refresh page

Comment: i am asking about html. whats common in them?

Answer (score 1):

Try this sample code, you can use it in your own way.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("change", "#select-ele", function() {
    var cur_val = $(this).val();
    $("[name='check-ele']").attr("checked", false);
    if (cur_val.length > 0) {
      $("[name='check-ele']").each(function() {
        var check_val = $(this).val();
        if ($.inArray(check_val, cur_val) > -1) {
          $(this).attr("checked", true);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-ele" multiple>
  <option value="1">Canvas</option>
  <option value="2">Acrylic</option>
  <option value="3">Cushion</option>
  <option value="4">Mug</option>
</select>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="check-ele" value="1">Canvas
<input type="checkbox" name="check-ele" value="2">Acrylic
<input type="checkbox" name="check-ele" value="3">Cushion
<input type="checkbox" name="check-ele" value="4">Mug
```

I have used [$.inArray](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) to check if checkbox value is selected in dropdown values.